# Pivot- turning rows to columns but keeping listing values underneath each column

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, pivot, tidyverse

I am new to R programming, and I am trying to get my Sites as columns and my numbers listed as values in separate rows underneath. Here's my data and what I've tried to do.

```r
matrix <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(1982,1923,3445,2345,12345,1234,"Site1","Site2","Site2","Site1","Site2","Site3"), nrow=6,ncol=2))

matrix <- matrix %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from= V2, values_from = V1)
```

I'm trying to get the following:

| Site1 | Site2 | Site3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1982 | 1923 | 1234 |
| 2345 | 3445 |  |
|  | 12345 |  |

Do I need to pivot_longer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's definitely still a `pivot_wider` - you just need to generate an id column to be used for specifying the unique rows to pivot against:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
matrix %>%
    group_by(V2) %>%
    mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
    pivot_wider(id_cols = id, names_from= V2, values_from = V1)
##     id Site1 Site2 Site3
##  <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>
##1     1 1982  1923  1234 
##2     2 2345  3445  NA   
##3     3 NA    12345 NA
```